# Adding data to record from the dashboard in Orchard CMS

Tags: c#, .net, database, orchardcms

Could you point me in the right way. The documentation is poorly written, and following the official documentation on creating content fields, parts and type didn't help me at all with completing my objective.

All I want to do is to create a record that has two properties/fields: Datetime Start and Datetime End.

I want to enter it from the backend, and save it to the database.

So far, the only thing that is working as I want it is the code written in the Migrations.cs for creating a table on the database, called CycleRecord.

How to modify it?

Comment: I would try to help, but probably can't, since I poorly wrote much of the Orchard documentation. ;) OK, seriously, what are you trying to do? (I'm afraid the question is poorly written ;p ) Why does it need to be a record? What should its relationship be to contents? Why isn't it a part?

Comment: Why not just attach 2 DateTime fields?

Comment: @BertrandLeRoy Wow, talking to the guy who is in Orchard steering commitee :) . I was struggling for few hours and I don't get it. I want to make CycleRecord from the back-end writing Start and End into database. That's it. It needs to be a record because later i will use it in my custom code on front-end :). Don't worry I know how to do that (at least I think I know).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 5 steps needed to create a part and store its data:

1: Create the record that represent the rows in the table

```
public class CyclePartRecord : ContentPartRecord
{
    public DateTime Start { get; set; }
    public DateTime End { get; set; }
}
```

2: Create the part that represents the part in Orchard

```
public class CyclePart : ContentPart<CyclePartRecord> {
    public DateTime Start {
        get { return Record.Start; }
        set { Record.Start = value; }
    }

    public DateTime End {
        get { return Record.End; }
        set { Record.End = value; }
    }
}
```

3: Create the migrations that create the table and its columns

```
public class Migrations : DataMigrationImpl {

    public int Create() {

        SchemaBuilder.CreateTable(typeof(CyclePartRecord).Name, table => table
            // Unique identifier etc.
            .ContentPartRecord()

            .Column<DateTime>("Start")
            .Column<DateTime>("End"));

        return 1;
    }
}
```

4: Create the handler to enable the storage of the records

```
public class CyclePartHandler : ContentHandler {
    public CyclePartHandler(IRepository<CyclePartRecord> repository) {
        // Enable storing the cyclepartrecord data
        Filters.Add(StorageFilter.For(repository));
    }
}
```

5: Create the drivers to enable the rendering of the display and editors

```
public class CyclePartDriver : ContentPartDriver<CyclePart> {
    protected override DriverResult Display(CyclePart part, string displayType, dynamic shapeHelper) {
        return ContentShape("Parts_Cycle", () => shapeHelper.Parts_Cycle(Model: part));
    }

    //GET
    protected override DriverResult Editor(CyclePart part, dynamic shapeHelper) {
        return ContentShape("Parts_Cycle_Edit",
            () => shapeHelper.EditorTemplate(
                TemplateName: "Parts/Cycle",
                Model: part,
                Prefix: Prefix));
    }

    //POST
    protected override DriverResult Editor(CyclePart part, IUpdateModel updater, dynamic shapeHelper) {

        updater.TryUpdateModel(part, Prefix, null, null);
        return Editor(part, shapeHelper);
    }
}
```

6: Create the edit view:

```
@model Maps.Models.MapPart

<fieldset>
    <legend>Cycle Fields</legend>

  <div class="editor-label">
      @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Start)
  </div>
  <div class="editor-field">
      @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Start)
      @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Start)
  </div>

  <div class="editor-label">
      @Html.LabelFor(model => model.End)
  </div>
  <div class="editor-field">
      @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.End)
      @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.End)
  </div>

</fieldset>
```

7: Create the display view

```
<h1>@T("Start")</h1>
<span>@Model.Start.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")</span>
<h1>@T("End")</h1>
<span>@Model.End.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")</span>
```

8: IMPORTANT! this step is forgotten often. If you cannot figure out why your part isn't displayed anywhere, always check your Placement.info! To display the editor and/or the part, it needs to be in this file

```
<Placement>
    <Place Parts_Cycle="Content:10"/>
    <Place Parts_Cycle_Edit="Content:7.5"/>
</Placement>
```

As I had too much time, I wrote this whole thing for you, but you also just might to take a look at this (excellent written ;) ) tutorial:

http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Writing-a-content-part

Comment: I did all of this, created type and part aswell , and when I publish it I can preview it, but I cannot see it in the database record that I've made.

Comment: Is there anything in the Logs?

Comment: Nope. But I've had problems with this line in the Handler.

`Filters.Add(new StorageFilter.For(repository));`
It says:
`Error 4 'Orchard.ContentManagement.Handlers.StorageFilter.For<TRecord>(Orchard.Data.IRepository<TRecord>)' is a 'method' but is used like a 'type' C:\Users\tomislavs\Desktop\Prometna sandbox\Orchard\src\Orchard.Web\Modules\Prometna.Pozivnice\Handlers\PozivnicaHandler.cs 17 43 Prometna.Pozivnice
`

Comment: Ah I see, the `new ` shouldn't be there

Comment: I've finaly managed to do it. One more question. When I save the data from the backend it saves to the database. Why when I manually change the record in database I don't see it in the backend?

Comment: That is because of how Orchard works. It uses cache and document storage to improve performance. You can see the document storage in the table Orchard_Framework_ContentItemRecord in the Data column

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84472/discussion-between-tomislav-and-devqon).